# How to modify a struct type in an llvm Module?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I need to update the address space of the properties in some of the structs in an llvm Module.  It is fairly straightforward to update a single struct type, by cloning it to a new type, with the appropriate new struct type.  It does need recursively applying the method to any child structs, but works ok.

But my challenge is how to update the usage of this struct in the Module?  There are two challenges I see:

- no obvious way to query which `Values`s are using the old struct type?
- it is possible to have pointer types, that also use the old type, so I will need to search for those too, somehow, possibly by searching exhaustively every pointer type I come across?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think I can address your concerns, assuming you're talking about something similar to  a ConstantStruct for example.

1. You can easily query for all uses or users with Value's member functions `Value::uses()` or `Value::users ()` respectively. It returns an `iterator_range` which you can use to loop over them. However, if you just want to replace the old struct with a new one, all you need is `Value::replaceAllUsesWith (Value *V)`. This applies to any `Value` in LLVM.
2. If you have stored pointers to the old struct yourself, these will indeed be invalidated and as you'd expect it is up to you to update them consistently. However, calling the `replaceAllUsesWith` function does ensure that on LLVM's side, pointers to the struct remain valid. This means that you don't have to worry about getting a pointer to the old struct if you would query the module again after having replaced all the uses, using the aforementioned method.

Comment: unfortuantely, `Value::uses()` only applies to a value, not a type. I'm not using a constantstruct, it is a struct used as the argument to a function, and throughout that function, and in other functions within hte same module.